# Most efficient way to convert bulk JSON object data into Kotlin objects?

Tags: json, kotlin, moshi

Where sending thousands of the same type of object, with numerous properties that have descriptive names (can be long), it's super inefficient, in terms of server RAM overhead, to send them as regular JSON data objects, so instead I have the server sending the data as follows:

```
{ "names": [<list of field names>], "values": [ [<list of object values>], ...] }
```

For the Web client, which maps some of the server field names to internal versions, it's a piece of cake to efficiently reconstitute the objects from this data (I've replaced specific object names for generic ones, for the sample code), where the mapping of the field names only has to be done once (instead of for every object instance):

```
// Map external object field names to internal names
var fieldNames = data.names, mappings = this.fieldMappings, fieldIndex;
for (var internalName in mappings) {
    if ((fieldIndex = fieldNames.indexOf(mappings[internalName])) != -1)
        fieldNames[fieldIndex] = internalName;
}

// Create array of objects from values array
var objects = [], objectValues = data.values;
for (var i = 0; i < objectValues.length; i++) {
    var values = objectValues[i];

    var obj = { };

    for (var j = 0; j < fieldNames.length; j++)
        obj[fieldNames[j]] = values[j];

    objects.push(obj);
}
```

Recreating this code in Python wouldn't present too much of an issue, with its *setattr* function, but Kotlin appears to be a whole different ball of wax, where the existing Kotlin Android based app I offered to upgrade is presently using Moshi to convert the standard JSON objects into internal objects (with the usual { "nameA" : valueA, "nameB": valueB, ...} format), with a JSONAdapter etc.

Any suggestions on how best to handle this bulk JSON data in Kotlin would be much appreciated, ideally where field names are again mapped just once.

Comment: I'm ptrobably missing sonething obvious, but why is the approach above less inefficient in terms on memory used?

Comment: @mattfreake by using values arrays, you eliminate repeating the property names for every single object, where if you're potentially sending thousands of objects, this overhead could add up, for a server that's responding to thousands of client requests

Comment: Oh yes  I missed that the values were nested like that.